# How to add dynamic component to Angular Router

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating pluggable angular app.

I've found the following article:

[Building an extensible Dynamic Pluggable Enterprise Application with Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/building-extensible-dynamic-pluggable-enterprise-application-with-angular-aed8979faba5)

Generally, everything works fine, but when I've tried to add angular router then I met some problems.

Currently, I'm not able to add the dynamically loaded component to the router.

I've tried something like this:

```
this.pluginLoader.load(pluginName).then(moduleFactory => {
              const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
              const entryComponent = (moduleFactory.moduleType as any).entry;
              const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
                entryComponent
              );

              this.router.config.push({
                path: `${pluginName}`,
                component: entryComponent
              });

              this.router.resetConfig(this.router.config);
              this.router.navigate([`/${pluginName}`]);
            });
```

But this code cause following error:

> core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for function(){this.x=!1}. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents

I've tried also use loadChildren property instead of the component property but I don't know what path should I use.

How can I add the component to the component factory, or how can I find a proper path for such components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, to add the dynamically loaded module to the angular router we have to use LoadChildren property, but directly from Route object. In this case, we have to create Route object first and then add it to the router config.

```
loadPlugin(pluginName: string) {
   this.pluginLoader.load(pluginName).then(moduleFactory => {

      const route: Route = {
          path: `${pluginName}`,
          loadChildren: () => moduleFactory
      };

      this.router.config.push(route);
   });

}
```